# 400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand. KeyError: 'question'

Tags: post, chatbot

Im tring to create a post method for openai chatbot using python

```
def chatbot_load():
    Index = GPTSimpleVectorIndex.load_from_disk('index.json')
    question = request.form['question']
    answer = Index.query(question)
    return jsonify({'status': 'success', 'response': str(answer)})
pass
```

It gives
400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent  a request that this server could not understand. KeyError: 'question'

Im trying output with swagger [image]
[image]